# How to match multiple substrings that occur after a specific substring?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to read out the server names from a nginx config file.

I need to use regex on a line like this:

server_name    this.com www.this.com someother-example.com;

I am using PHP's `preg_match_all()` and I've tried different things so far:

```
/^(?:server_name[\s]*)(?:(.*)(?:\s*))*;$/m
// no output

/^(?:server_name[\s]*)((?:(?:.*)(?:\s*))*);$/m
//  this.com www.this.com someother-example.com
```

But I can't find the right one to list the domains as separate values.

```
[  
    0 => 'this.com',  
    1 => 'www.this.com',  
    2 => 'someother-example.com'  
]
```

Comment: [Bob's your uncle:](https://regex101.com/r/sB0eG6/1) `(?:server_name|\G(?!<^))\s*\K[^;\s]+`. TLDR: this has nothing to do with "recursive patterns".

Comment: If they are separated by space sign why don't you just explode by space sign?

Comment: Thanks! Without the '<' it does what I want!

Comment: @user3776824 ah, that was a typo on my part! I meant to write `(?<!^)` but `(?!^)` should also do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

as Bob's your uncle wrote:

`(?:server_name|\G(?!^))\s*\K[^;|\s]+`

Does the trick!

Comment: _Bob's your uncle_ and _Fanny's your aunt_ (code-only) answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Please do your best to explain every answer that you post here.  You will find that very few researchers will have any clue about what `\G` (continue metacharacter) does.

Comment: This highlights a recurring problem on Stackoverflow when volunteers use comments to provide answers.  In this case, a good explanation was not delivered by the person who originally provided a working solution.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html

Answer (score 0):

The plain English requirement is to extract the space-delimited strings that immediately follow `server_name` then several spaces.

The dynamic duo of `\G` (start from the start / continue from the end of the last match) and `\K` (restart the fullstring match) will be the heroes of the day.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Pgrv8))

```
$string = "server_name    this.com www.this.com someother-example.com;";

var_export(preg_match_all('~(?:server_name +|\G(?!^) )\K[^; ]+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'no matches');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'this.com',
  1 => 'www.this.com',
  2 => 'someother-example.com',
)
```

Pattern Explanation:

```
(?:                  # start of non-capturing group (to separate piped expressions from end of the pattern)
  server_name +      # literally match "server_name" followed by one or more spaces
  |                  # OR
  \G(?!^)            # continue searching for matches immediately after the previous match, then match a single space
)                    # end of the non-capturing group
\K                   # restart the fullstring match (aka forget any previously matched characters in "this run through")
[^; ]+               # match one or more characters that are NOT a semicolon or a space
```

The reason that you see `\G(?!^)` versus just `\G` (which, for the record, will work just fine on your sample input) is because `\G` can potentially match from two different points by its default behavior.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html

If you were to use the naked `\G` version of my pattern AND add a single space to the front of the input string, you would not make the intended matches.  `\G` would successfully start at the beginning of the string, then match the single space, then `server_name` via the negated character class `[^; ]`.

For this reason, disabling `\G`'s "start at the start of the string` ability makes the pattern more stable/reliable/accurate.

`preg_match_all()` returns an array of matches.  The first element `[0]` is a collection of fullstring matches (what is matched regardless of capture groups).  If there are any capture groups, they begin from `[1]` and increment with each new group.

Because you need to match `server_name` before targeting the substrings to extract, using capture groups would mean a bloated output array and an unusable `[0]` subarray of fullstring matches.

To extract the desired space-delimited substrings and omit `server_name` from the results, `\K` is used to "forget" the characters that are matched prior to finding the desired substrings.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html

Without the `\K` to purge the unwanted leading characters, the output would be:

```
array (
  0 => 'server_name    this.com',
  1 => ' www.this.com',
  2 => ' someother-example.com',
)
```

If anyone is comparing my answer to user3776824's or HamZa's:

1. I am electing to be very literal with space character matching.  There are 4 spaces after `server_name`, so I could have used an exact quantifier `{4}` but opted for a bit of flexibility here.  `\s*` isn't the most ideal because when matching there will always be "one or more spaces" to match.  I don't have a problem with `\s`, but to be clear it does match spaces, tabs, newlines, and line returns.
2. I am using `(?!^)` -- a negative lookahead -- versus `(?<!^)` -- a negative lookbehind because it does the same job with a less character.  You will more commonly see the use of `\G(?!^)` from experienced regex craftsmen.
3. There is never a need to use "alternative" syntax (`|`) within a character class to separate values.  user3776824's pattern will actually exclude pipes in addition to semicolons and spaces -- though I don't expect any negative impact in the outcome based on the sample data.  The pipe in the pattern simply should not be written.